# Using ggplot with non-numeric data

Tags: r

My dataset (at the bottom) describes conservation status of various frog species that are either resistant or susceptible to a particular disease "Bd". The thing is, not much data is available (for example, many genome sequences are missing). I want to see whether lack of data availability correlates with conservation status or disease susceptibility (if the frogs are dying too rapidly, we won't have data!) Is used the following command to change some columns from characters into factors:

```
df <- mutate_at(df, vars(IUCN_Red_List_status, Bd_resistance, Genome_availability, Phylum, Last.assessed), as.factor)
```

I want to visualize and compare which species are increasing/stable/declining (IUCN_Red_List_status column), which species have NAs in the columns Genome_availability and GeneID, and which species are Bd resistant (N = no, Y = yes, U = unknown). I attempted the command below but the image is unhelpful. The thing is, none of this data is numeric, so I'm struggling to create any graphs. Will someone please help me get a start on this project?

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Species, group = IUCN_Red_List_status))



structure(list(Species = c("Lithobates catesbeianus", "Lithobates sylvatica", 
"Xenopus laevis", "Xenopus tropicalis", "Pyxicephalus adspersus", 
"Nanorana parkeri", "Rhinella marina", "Rana temporaria", "Oophaga pumilio", 
"Amolops mantzorum", "Rana saharica", "Pseudacris regilla", "Babina daunchina", 
"Odorrana schmackeri"), Phylum = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Anura ", 
"Chordata"), class = "factor"), IUCN_Red_List_status = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Decreasing", 
"Increasing", "Stable"), class = "factor"), Last.assessed = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("2004", 
"2005", "2008", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), 
    National_status = c("LC", "LC", "LC", "LC", "NT", "LC", "LC", 
    "LC", "U", "U", "LC", "LC", "LC", "NT"), Bd_resistance = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "U", "Y"), class = "factor"), Genome_availability = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), Gene_name = c("ranalexin", NA, NA, 
    "NPC intracellular cholesterol transporter 1", NA, "uncharacterized LOC", 
    NA, "temporin G precursor", NA, "pleurain-B-MT1 antimicrobial peptide precursor", 
    "temporin-SHe precursor", "temporin-3PR precursor", "peptide-DN4", 
    "breinin-1S precursor"), GeneID = c("S69903.1", NA, NA, "XM_004915212.4", 
    NA, "XR_001941307.1", NA, "Y09395.1", NA, "HQ128621.1", "FN557008.1", 
    "JQ511833.1", "Q1286626.1", "AJ971790.1"), Score = c(435, 
    NA, NA, 43.7, NA, 98.7, NA, 288, NA, 229, 255, 266, 224, 
    231), E.value = c(8e-118, NA, NA, 0.008, NA, 3e-20, NA, 4e-79, 
    NA, 8e-62, 9e-70, 2e-61, 2e-61, 4e-62), Identities = c("268/283", 
    NA, NA, "41/52", NA, "93/119", NA, "237/281", NA, "146/155", 
    "171/187", "147/158", "145/155", "141/146"), Identities.percent = c(95L, 
    NA, NA, 79L, NA, 78L, NA, 84L, NA, 94L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 97L
    ), Gaps = c("6/283", NA, NA, " 3/52", NA, "0/119", NA, "11/281", 
    NA, "3/155", "3/187", "4/158", "3/155", "3/146"), Gaps.percent = c(2L, 
    NA, NA, 5L, NA, 0L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of what you want the graphs to look like? Can you describe it? If you don't have a relatively good idea of what you want, I would suggest asking a question on stats.stackexchange first to figure out what sort of analysis/summary statistics you actually want to plot.

Comment: Hi @Ree Nadeau! My impression is that your question isn't really about programming, but rather asking for ideas for visualization. That may be opinion-based (off-topic for SO). Thus, first you need to decide what you want. Have a look e.g. here: [The R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/) and [Visualizing Multivariate Categorical Data](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/129-visualizing-multivariate-categorical-data/) and we are happy to help when you have a _concrete programming question_. Cheers.

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks, everyone. I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I'm still learning how to format questions appropriately. I'll definitely keep those links in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question essentially boils down to "how do I plot 4 dimensions of factorial data on a 2-d plot?". One answer is to use the x-axis, the y-axis, a fill scale and a facet to represent the 4 dimensions you are plotting:

```r
df$missing_geneId <- "Has Gene Info"
df$missing_geneId[is.na(df$GeneID)] <- "Missing Gene Info"

ggplot(df, aes(Bd_resistance, Species, fill = IUCN_Red_List_status,
               colour = IUCN_Red_List_status)) + 
  geom_tile(alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ missing_geneId) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is incredible! I have so much to learn, thank you so much!